# Haskell IO sharing parameters

Tags: haskell, syntax, io

In Haskell, is it possible to share user input from one IO function to the other?

For instance, if I had:

```
  main = do
         putStrLn "Give me a number!"
         my_stuff <- getLine 
         let nump = read (my_stuff)::Int
         another_function nump
```

Where another_function is also an IO function with a `do` construct.

```
another_function nump = do
                          putStrLn nump
                          putStrLn "Try again!"
                          main
```

This *would* make sense in the fantasy-world Haskell interpreter I have in my head. However, in the real world: my_stuff is unbound in another_function; and in main, my_stuff requires to be of type IO t but it isn't.

The above code would (most probably) be very offensive to Haskellers, yet I hope that it conveyed what exactly I'm aiming for...

How do I work around this?

Comment: The type of `another_function` would be very useful. Or at least show its implementation if you aren't sure about the type. It should be along the lines of `[String] -> IO something`, from the error message seems you made it takes an `IO` parameter.

Comment: @delnan Well, I haven't really written out the another_function. All I wrote was putStrLn my_stuff, where my_stuff was supposed to be a String. I wanted to see if you could *do* "parameter passing".

Comment: `s <- getLine; putStrLn s` should work just fine. Perhaps there's something subtle you're missing in your summary? Providing small isolated examples is great in general, but sometimes something vital is lost in the process...

Comment: @delnan I think you may have misunderstood the question. So I decided to clarify it a little bit. Take a look if you're still interested in helping out :)

Comment: Well, I want to help. But the code you posted now is still fine, ignoring that you have to use `show` to convert `nump` back to a string for `putStrLn`, as it's an `Int` (and that doesn't fit the error you describe). I fear we'll have to bring the big guns in - please copy and paste your exact code and how you compile/run it. See http://www.ideone.com/kLMr7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works. Is this what you want to do? If not, can you provide with the code that doesn't work?

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Give me a number!"
    my_stuff <- getLine 
    let nump = read (my_stuff)::Int
    another_function nump

another_function nump = do
    putStrLn $ show nump
    putStrLn "Try again!"
    main
```

Comment: Not really related to the original question, but I would probably rewrite `read (my_stuff)::Int` since the parens don't actually do anything. Either as `(read my_stuff)::Int` or just `read my_stuff :: Int`.